# PDI - How to keep Transformation run even an error occur?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a transformation with several steps that run by batch script using Windows Task Scheduler.

Sometimes the first step or the n steps fail and it stops the entire transformation.

I want to transformation to run from start to end regardless of any errors, any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)One way is to “error handling”, however it is not available for all the steps. You can right click on the step and check whether error handling option is available or not.

2) if you are getting errors because of incorrect datatype, for example: you are expecting a integer value and for some specific record you may get string value so it may fail , for handling such situation you can use data validation step.

Basically you can implement logic based on the transformation you have created. Above are some of the General methods.

Comment: Yes, that the answer. Basically, if you get an error it is because something unexpected occurred. Correct it before it happens. Otherwise will end up with perpetually loading partial data. And this will be even harder to decode.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you called "Error Handling". Though your transformation runs with some Errors, you still want your transformation to continue to run.

Situations: 
        - Data type issues in the data stream. 
                 Ex: say you have a column X of data type integer but by mistake you got string value. then you can define Error handling to capture all these records. 
        - while Processing json data.
                 Ex: the path you mentioned to retrieve a value of json field and for some data node the path can't identify or missing it. you can define error handling to capture all missing path details.
        - while Update table
             - If you are updating a table with some key, and if the key was not available as it is coming from input stream then an error will occur. you can define error handling here also.